# grails executable war deployment

Tags: tomcat, grails

Without going into why we have let this upgrade languish so long, we are breaking up our Grails 2.2.4 (Java 6) monolith as we upgrade to Grails 3.3.0 (Java 8). The idea is to upgrade incrementally rather than trying to do a big bang upgrade which seems like a really good thing. While we are at it we would like to end up with something more service-based than monolithic as we go.

To keep the external dependencies to a minimum I decided to use the executable war deployment model, so as we deploy our build artifact to various environments up through production things can only differ based on defined configuration elements.

I have moved the first piece into a web service and all seems well in my local environment; that is to say, I have refactored the monolith to call the service, and have the service running using java -jar from the command line. Now I am trying to integrate it with our automated build and deployment tool (Bamboo).

Our current process (for the monolith) is to stop the Tomcat instance (shutdown.sh), deploy the war, and restart Tomcat (startup.sh). How can I accomplish this - specifically, stop the running instance/service - when it is running as an executable war?

My first thought is to write a script that will find the pid for the particular java -jar process and kill it, but that seems inelegant. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: May be deploy your services in docker containers and start stop containers as needed !

Comment: Yeah, introducing Docker, Spring Boot, or something of that ilk would definitely work, but I was hoping to delay the investment in that effort once we have established the value. Investing a lot up front to start the experiment does not feel very agile. Hoping there is a way to make the executable war feature of Grails production ready.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an executable war/jar, this script[0] is embedded in it, so you can execute it like so `./foo.jar stop`

And you can see, they just send the kill command to the process. It's an interrupt so the process sees that and starts a clean shutdown. There is also a force stop if it does not shut down cleanly which runs `kill -9`.

This script also behaves like an init.d script so you can just link it to your `/etc/init.d/foo` and run commands like `service foo start|stop|restart`

Lastly you can expose the shutdown port, calling that port will start a clean shutdown as well. (of course do not expose that port to the internet)

[0] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script